# Cloud formation failed to create Security group with VPCIdNotSpecified

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

**Problem :**

While creating Security group using cloud formation template, it fails with VPCIdNotSpecified error even though I have provided VPCID as an input.

**Error Message:**
No default VPC for this user (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: VPCIdNotSpecified; Request ID: d45efd39-16ce-4c0c-9e30-746b39f4ff44; Proxy: null)

**Background :**
I have deleted the default VPC that comes with the account and created my own VPC. Also, I am getting the VPC ID as a parameter input. \1/used aws cli to verify the template and its good.
All the input parameters were fetch correctly and shown in summary page of cloud formation creation. It even shows the VPCID which is matched.

Code :

````
Parameters:
 VPCName:
    Description: Enter the VPC that you want to launch the instance
    Type : AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    ConstraintDescription: VPC must be already existing
Resources:
 HANASG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: XSASG
      GroupDescription: This will allow connections between your RDP instance & HANA Box
      **VpcId: !Ref VPCName**
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          SourceSecurityGroupName: !Ref RdpSgName
          FromPort: 0
          ToPort: 65535
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 0
          ToPort: 65535
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: HANAXSASG```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest [re-creating the default VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/deleted-default-vpc/) in the VPC section of the console per amazons instructions. Its a good idea NOT to use the default VPC and to create and configure your own as you describe. Internally there is something special about the default VPC that is not exposed via the console or API. I suspect that is the root cause of your issue, and creating a new default VPC should fix it.

AFAIK theres no issue in renaming the default VPC (mine are named `Default VPC - DO NOT USE`).

Comment: You are right. I had to just recreate the default VPC. It uses that for some internal work. However, I got my SG created in my desired VPC.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of a SG is limited within a VPC. So its a mandatory field while creating a SecurityGroup to specify a value for `VpcId` .

It may be an item under EC2 buts its scope is within a VPC. You cannot create a SG without specifying a VPC. Just like you cant create an EC2 without specifying its Subnet and VPC.

Can you remove ** and try?